# How do I enable verbose logging for the OSX Music app?

Tags: macos, music, optical-drive

I've been importing CDs using Music on OSX (Catalina). Some of them refuse to import. I'd like to see what's happening in the log files, but I can't work out which file Music uses or how to increase the logging level. If this was a Java app I'd look for the log4j.properties file, but this isn't Java.

When this behavior happens the Music app will lock up and the optical drive won't eject. Music will spike to using 99% of the CPU. I'm unable to eject the disc. Sometimes Music or the Finder will report that the disc has been ejected, but it hasn't. I have to force-quit Music, unplug the optical drive, plug the drive back in, and eject the CD before Music starts reading it.

I am 95% sure the issue is with the cd themselves. Some are close to 25 years old and may have too many scratches etc to be read. Still, I'd like to have a look at the log files to see if I can get some of the data off the discs if not all.

Notes:

- I don't have XCode.
- I have error correction enabled in Music.
- I've been looking at the Console app. It wasn't much help.

Update: I didn't have "Include Debug Messages" enabled in Console. Thanks, @bmike!

Comment: You don’t need Xcode to [look in the console app](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/welcome/mac), increase debug level - is that what you seek? I’m guessing you already enabled use error correction in music app, so please edit in if you found that and it’s not helpful.